# How to host workflow Foundation in winservice?

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

please let me know how a workflow (.net 4.0) can be hosted on windows service. is it the same way we were doing in .net 3.0/3.5. or any better way in new version.

Please help.

(my scenario: i have created workflow using flowchart, this flow has to run for eavry 1 min)

Thanks/ Yogesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to run the workflow synchronously on the current thread, you can call [WorkflowInvoker.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowinvoker.invoke.aspx) (several overloads, including generic ones).

You may want to consider using [WorkflowApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication.aspx), as it uses a separate thread (asynchronous). So long as your workflow isn't a WCF service, this should be sufficient.